# Direct link of Youtube video

Tags: android, youtube

I would like to get from the link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzmpH7eaA4k the direct link of the video, something like: http://www.youtube.com/(...).mp4

Is it possible? I have seen a lot of threads that use "www.youtube.com/get_video_info" and other ways but I think that all of them are obsolete right now.

How can I get the URL that I need?

Comment: do you want a direct link to this video only?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I do not only need of this video, I need to know how can I get this link of any video.

Comment: @Jorge181 refer this one http://www.kpbird.com/2012/12/youtube-android-player-api-tutorial.html

Answer (score 8):

There is a easy way to find youtube direct video link using VLC Media Player.
Open VLC -> Media -> Open Network Stream -> Network -> Enter the youtube link (e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FKEy_RWwQk). 
Now open the playlist-> Right click on Video-> Information -> You will find the below part of the screen in [location](http://r2---sn-hunpoqp5-h55e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1390263704&sver=3&source=youtube&id=ec5284cbf456c109&ratebypass=yes&ms=au&mt=1390240583&mv=m&sparams=id%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ipbits=0&fexp=900379%2C936910%2C936913%2C907231%2C921090&itag=22&upn=f_xasqhflDI&ip=116.203.170.237&key=yt5&signature=5DA69A5385684960B1B9883B2FE0D2BDEB029BED.0A24AD053AE670C6B6CAE8FAB8DC7810CC11A338) textbox.This is the direct link of the video.You can open it in browser or save it to your local system.

Comment: this does not work for me. The location field shows nothing.

Comment: The url does not have .mp4 at the end, though.

Comment: Any updates on this in 2020? Location field shows the same link on my device

Answer (score 0):

If you want the direct Link to download a Video you have to use the "stram_map" attribute with the specific itag(quality). A great example how you can get the download link is shown here: [Get the download URL for YouTube video (Android/Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240011/get-the-download-url-for-youtube-video-android-java) you can directly play the video in your own player or you could use it to download the video to your device.

Answer (score -1):

Well I would go nab the link myself for you but you have the video not available in my country, USA, just simply click the share tab under your video and use that link.

Comment: I do not want this link: http://youtu.be/GzmpH7eaA4k, I need the direct link of the video, not the link of the youtube page.

For example, imagine that I need a picture of this web: http://bitelia.com/2013/05/anadir-efectos-a-videos-de-youtube

I do not need this link, i need:

http://s1.hipertextual.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/4/files/2013/05/YouTube-Principal.jpg

That is what I need from youtube

Comment: Ohhh I see, are you trying to embed it to a website?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that get_video_info is deprecated. Try in stead:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/GzmpH7eaA4k
```

Keep up to date with the youtube api here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Comment: this is no longer available